# getting an IllegalStateException while getting a list of custom type from SavedInstanceState

Tags: android, kotlin, exception, parcelable, onsaveinstancestate

I have a Question class implementing Parcelable that acts as a bridge between myquiz.db and dbHelper class. The thing I have to do is restore the state after the device is rotated. This is the code in onSaveInstanceState():

```
override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle?, outPersistentState: PersistableBundle?) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState, outPersistentState)
        outState?.putInt(KEY_SCORE, score)
        outState?.putInt(KEY_QUES_COUNT, questionCounter)
        outState?.putBoolean(KEY_ANSWERED, answered)
        outState?.putLong(KEY_MILLIS_LEFT, timeLeftInMillis)
        outState?.putParcelableArrayList(KEY_QUES_LIST, list)
    }
```

This is the code where I am restoring a list from savedInstanceState:

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        val dbHelper = QuizDbHelper(this)
        list = dbHelper.getAllQuestions()
        totalQuestions = list.size
        list.shuffle()
        textDefaultColor = rb1.textColors
        textDefaultColorcd = timer.textColors
        nextQuestion()
    } else {
        **list = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList(KEY_QUES_LIST)**
        totalQuestions = list.size
        score = savedInstanceState.getInt(KEY_SCORE)
        answered = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(KEY_ANSWERED)
        questionCounter = savedInstanceState.getInt(KEY_QUES_COUNT)
        currQuestion = list[questionCounter - 1]
        timeLeftInMillis = savedInstanceState.getLong(KEY_MILLIS_LEFT)

        if (!answered) {
            startTimer()
        } else {
            updateCoundownText()
            correctAnswer()
        }
    }
```

When I run the app I get this error: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: savedInstanceState.getPa…eArrayList(KEY_QUES_LIST) must not be null` first line in the else block Type mismatch. Also when I hover a mouse pointer on this line, it shows:

```
Required:
ArrayList<Question>
Found:
ArrayList<Question!>?
```

Declaration of list : `private lateinit var list: ArrayList<Question>`

Question.class

```
class Question() : Parcelable {
private lateinit var question: String
private lateinit var option1: String
private lateinit var option2: String
private lateinit var option3: String
private var answerNr = 0

constructor(question: String, option1: String, option2: String, option3: String, answerNr: Int) : this() {
    this.question = question
    this.option1 = option1
    this.option2 = option2
    this.option3 = option3
    this.answerNr = answerNr
}

constructor(parcel: Parcel) : this() {
    parcel.readString()
    parcel.readString()
    parcel.readString()
    parcel.readString()
    parcel.readInt()
}


fun getQuestion(): String? {
    return question
}

fun setQuestion(question: String) {
    this.question = question
}

fun getOpt1(): String? {
    return option1
}

fun setOpt1(option1: String) {
    this.option1 = option1
}

fun getOpt2(): String? {
    return option2
}

fun setOpt2(option2: String) {
    this.option2 = option2
}

fun getOpt3(): String? {
    return option3
}

fun setOpt3(option3: String) {
    this.option3 = option3
}

fun getAnswerNo(): Int {
    return answerNr
}

fun setAnswerNo(answerNr: Int) {
    this.answerNr = answerNr
}

override fun writeToParcel(parcel: Parcel, flags: Int) {
    parcel.writeString(question)
    parcel.writeString(option1)
    parcel.writeString(option2)
    parcel.writeString(option3)
    parcel.writeInt(answerNr)
}

override fun describeContents(): Int {
    return 0
}

companion object CREATOR : Parcelable.Creator<Question> {
    override fun createFromParcel(parcel: Parcel): Question {
        return Question(parcel)
    }

    override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<Question> {
        return newArray(size)
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

In the onSaveInstanceState method, you are calling super first and then storing the state. So list is always null and you have declared the list as non-nullable, so it's throwing exception.

Update the code:

```
 override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle?, outPersistentState: PersistableBundle?) {
            outState?.putInt(KEY_SCORE, score)
            outState?.putInt(KEY_QUES_COUNT, questionCounter)
            outState?.putBoolean(KEY_ANSWERED, answered)
            outState?.putLong(KEY_MILLIS_LEFT, timeLeftInMillis)
            outState?.putParcelableArrayList(KEY_QUES_LIST, list)
            super.onSaveInstanceState(outState, outPersistentState)
        }
```

Comment: I have initialized the list in onCreate()

Comment: I understand, What I'm trying to say is list is of non-null type but the line savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList(KEY_QUES_LIST) is returning null. I have mentioned the reason why it is returning null.

Comment: I did according to your solution, but it is not working!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with how `list` is defined and how it is being restored from the `Bundle`. When restoring the saved instance state, the return value of `getParcelableArrayList()` is nullable. So your code would need to look like this:

```
val restoredList = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList(KEY_QUES_LIST)
restoredList?.also {
    list = it
}
```

Comment: I have defined it like this: private var list: ArrayList<Question> = arrayListOf()

Comment: Updated the answer based on new details.

Comment: What are you seeing now?